# Test String extension in Objective c

Tags: swift, string, testing

I have this in my project -

```
extension String {
    func doSomething() -> String {
        return "doSomething"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write an Objective C test for it. (This is an SDK that can be used by Objective C projects) but when calling -

```
NSString* actualResult = [string doSomething];
```

I'm getting this error -

```
No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'doSomething'
```

How can it be done?

Comment: You need to mark the method `@objc`, so that it gets registered with the ObjC runtime. It should also be an extension on `Foundation.NSString`, not `Swift.String`.

Comment: I've tried on NSString but the same error appears, @objc can only be added to classes not structs

Comment: `I've tried on NSString but the same error appears` You tried what? `@objc can only be added to classes not structs` But `NSString` isn't a struct, it's a class.

Comment: @ozd: did you check the answer? did it work?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I already tried that.
In my case, it was a specific access problem between models. 
I'm accepting your answer anyway for others to learn from because I think it's correct in these kinds of cases.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried on NSString but the same error appears, @objc can only be
>   added to classes not structs

Only adding `@objc` won't be sufficient, in order to access swift function inside your Objective-C file you have to import `<ProductModuleName>-Swift.h` in your .m file

For example

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "StackOverflow-Swift.h"

@interface SampleClass : NSObject

@end

@implementation SampleClass

- (void)test {
    NSString *testing = @"abcd";
    [testing doSomething];
}


@end
```

Finally

```
public extension NSString {
    @objc func doSomething() -> String {
        return "doSomething"
    }
}
```